# Allowing UITextField characters to render outside bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, drawrect

I have a problem with UITextField when I wish to render characters like Å and such within its rect.

The top of it is being clipped out, Making the Å look like an A.

In some cases i have solved it with a custom UITextField like this :

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y+5;
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

Which works when the text is just being displayed normally like this :

[image]

But when you start editing the text, its like the drawTextInRect is no longer applied, and the top of the characters disappear again.

Like so:

[image]

Does anyone else have ideas to how to fix this ?

Comment: you can't just increase the size of the field? And from your screenshot, it doesn't look like it is correctly centered. Are you modifying the standard UITextField here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` instead to adjust the text rect in all circumstances. I suspect that `UITextField` uses a label when you don't edit the text and something else when you do and that only one of them calls `drawTextInRect:` in particular.

Comment: This does not seem to do the trick. The text is still in the same place, and if i use this instead of drawTextInRect, the glyphs are being cut, and I'm back to having Å appear as A.